# Are you allowed to register a .com.au domain that contains a famous brand's trademark?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, legal, domain-registrar, personal-website

Can I register this domain `www.googlecloud.com.au`?

Is there any law preventing this?

Comment: Registrars are not supposed to allow someone to register a trademarked name. So might anyway. However, your domain name is a trademark infringement and you will lose your domain name in a nano-second and all your money etc. So the answer is, "Of course not! Why would you think you could?"

Comment: No clue. But I will be happy to be sued by Google. Might become overnight celebrity. Thanks for comment though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register it in some registrars. It's not a problem, and it's completley legit to register something that is nonexisting.

But, In this case, **when the DNS is propagated**, you'll lose your domain name and everything.

I tried it already before 3 years for one client with a different name and he lost the money and domain.

Cheers.

Comment: Who can take it away? because the domain is up and running and I never had any problem.

Comment: So, you have domain up and running and you are asking question "can you register domain?" Nice logic mate.

Comment: I don't know what's behind this, but if the company uses the logo from google etc...

Comment: in my book, it's really stupid to have a firm named after other firm. Lack of creativity perhaps or just a fraud, dunno.

Comment: I did my question that way to find out whether you really know the answer or not? By the sound of it you are just guessing. It is not a firm just a domain. And that is business. Google is possibly stealing your information and sells it to everyone even governments.

Answer (score 1):

As you are speaking about the .au ccTLD I will add that for `.com.au` domain names as well as `.net.au` domain names there is a regulated requirement by the auDA (registry for the .au ccTLD) which mandates that you have to have a verifiable business affiliation with the chosen name (such as if your company is named acme widgets and you choose a domain of acmewidgets.com.au). Furthermore for a .com.au or .net.au domain name business registration details such as an Australian Business Number is required as part of the verification process and most of the auDA certified registrar's are required to do at least a basic assessment of the domain name to make sure that it or a part of it does not appear to infringe on someone's trademark. Additionally as @Josip says the domain could be taken from you with no refund as the terms clearly state that the domain will be disabled for trademark infringement and that you as the customer will not be entitled to a refund.

Comment: I dont think many people would worry about $22 registration cost. You could say I am providing google cloud services which is a general service. I think one can argue that googlecloud is a generic name for providing generic services.

Comment: This may work with older tld's like .com and .net but the restrictions that are in place with the .au ccTLD are very strict for this exact reason. What you say about the argument of selling Google cloud services is true you could make that argument but the fact that the domain contains a trademark name and you don't have authority to use that trademark name will prevent the registration, and if you somehow make it past the initial screening the recourses that trademark holders have under the auDA terms don't make it worthwhile at all.